# How can change txt file real time

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop, awk, sed

I need help about bash shell
I want change content in snmptrap.txt like result.txt using info.txt at real time.

content add snmptrap.txt end of line at real time so I want add change content on result.txt

smtptrap.txt:

```
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 hello1 AAA05056 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 hello2 hello2 AAA05056 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 hello3 AAA05056 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 hello4 AAA05056
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 hello5 AAA05056
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 test1 AAA05056
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 test2 AAA05056
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 test3 AAA05056
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 test4 hello2 AAA05056
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 test5 hello2 AAA05056
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 hello1 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 hello2 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 hello3 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 hello4 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 hello5 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 test1 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 test2 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 test3 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 test4 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 test5 AAA05010 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 hello1 AAA05000
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 hello2 AAA05000 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 hello3 AAA05000 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 hello4 AAA05000 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 hello5 AAA05000 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 test1 AAA05000 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 test2 AAA05000
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 test3 AAA05000
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 test4 AAA05000
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 10.1 test5 AAA05000
```

I want change matching use info.txt
info.txt:

```
100.300;AAA05056
100.200;AAA05010
100.100;AAA05000
```

result.txt should look like this:

```
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.300 hello1 AAA05056 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.300 hello2 hello2 AAA05056 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.300 hello3 AAA05056 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.300 hello4 AAA05056
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.300 hello5 AAA05056
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.300 test1 AAA05056
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.300 test2 AAA05056
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.300 test3 AAA05056
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.300 test4 hello2 AAA05056
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.300 test5 hello2 AAA05056
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.200 hello1 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.200 hello2 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.200 hello3 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.200 hello4 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.200 hello5 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.200 test1 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.200 test2 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.200 test3 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.200 test4 AAA05010
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.200 test5 AAA05010 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.100 hello1 AAA05000
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.100 hello2 AAA05000 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.100 hello3 AAA05000 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.100 hello4 AAA05000 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.100 hello5 AAA05000 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.100 test1 AAA05000 
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.100 test2 AAA05000
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.100 test3 AAA05000
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.100 test4 AAA05000
2015/10/07  "General" 10.2 - ZBXTRAP 100.100 test5 AAA05000
```

Comment: I think you swapped AAA05000 with AAA05056

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's#^([^;]*);(.*)#/\2/s/\\S+/\1/6#' file2 | sed -rf - file1
```

This transforms the second file into a sed script which is used to transform the first file.

The second field of the second file is used as a lookup and the first field of the second file as the replacement for the sixth field in the first file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example

```
 $ awk -F"[; ]" 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}  $9 in a{$7=a[$9]}1' file2 file1
```

will do the job, however your output doesn't match the mappings provided please check.

One way to capture updates to the input file is using `tail -f`.  For example.

```
 $ awk ... file2 <(tail -f file1) >> output &
```

will start a background process.  You can monitor updates in output by

```
 $ tail -f output
```

Comment: thank you. and content add snmptrap.txt end of line at real time so I want add change content on result.txt. can you help that?

Comment: what does real time mean?

Comment: every second add content new line end of snmptrap.txt file.

Comment: OK got it, one way to do it you can `tail -f` the file to the awk script as a background process, which can then write it out when there is an update.

Comment: How can use tail -f 
awk -F"[; ]" 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}  $NF in a{$10=a[$NF]}1' info.txt snmptraps.txt | tail -1
I make this one but not work

Comment: i think this script but not work. tail -1 snmptrap.txt | awk -F"[; ]" 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next} $NF in a{$10=a[$NF]}1' info.txt >result.txt

Comment: It works but you have to do it correctly.  First it's `tail -f`, second you have two input files and second one is changing, you have to feed it accordingly.

Comment: thank you. I check your script. it's work. But output file update slowlly and some text cut out. cut out text write in output file after some second. I guess tail command has buffer or deley time. can you speed up script work time?